# Django external mysql db connection in test complains "unknown database"

Tags: mysql, django, django-unittest

In my django project I have a few database connections:

eg.

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": "awesome",
        ...
    },
    "other_1": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": "other_1",
        "TEST": {"MIRROR": default}
        ...
    },
    "other_2": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "NAME": "other_2",
        "TEST": {"MIRROR": default}
    }
}
```

Note:

1. The `default` and `other_1` both are `postgres` backends and
   `other_2` is `mysql` backend.
2. I added `"TEST": {"MIRROR": default}` to the extra database config in a bid to avoid those databases being created during test. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33541073/342553).

Problem:

When I run the test, it complains about `Unknown database 'test_awesome'`, the stack trace shows it's from MYSQL backend:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jlin/virtualenvs/awesome-1SH6mAZ2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1005, in setUpClass
    if not connections_support_transactions():
  File "/Users/jlin/virtualenvs/awesome-1SH6mAZ2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 970, in connections_support_transactions
...
File "/Users/jlin/virtualenvs/awesome-1SH6mAZ2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 85, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jlin/virtualenvs/awesome-1SH6mAZ2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'test_awesome'")
```

If I comment out the `other_2` connection, the test runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is due to having backend?

I dug into the `setup_database` [code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/test/utils/#setup_databases), and if I remove `other_2` in the `mirrored_aliases` dict, then my test code works fine.

So I created a test runner class to remove the `other_2` connection because it's too deep into the code to remove from `mirriored_aliases`.

```
class TestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    def setup_databases(self, **kwargs):
        # to get around this problem
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54189925/django-external-mysql-db-connection-in-test-complains-unknown-database
        settings.DATABASES.pop('other_2', None)
        return super(TestRunner, self).setup_databases(**kwargs)
```